# EAGLE 6.3 library with basic parts

Tags: cad

Hello i haven't been using EAGLE for a while now and had mostly forgot where to get any good and complete library of basic parts like resistors, LEDs, transistors... I have tried to find a library i need on [EAGLE web page](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/downloads/libraries), but i haven't found any, that would offer quite large amount of basic parts.

If anyone could point me to a library with a good and large set of basic parts he would really save my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sparkfun Eagle libraries are quite good. Download at https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries

Answer (score -1):

dear you can use "ORCAD" software rather than using EAGLE as it is easy in use and easy availability of its libraries on net.

Comment: Is ORCAD available on Linux? If not i am not interested.